# std::tuple::get returning const Type&&

Tags: c++, tuples, c++14, rvalue-reference, c++17

I just read the updated interface for C++17 for `std::tuple::get` on cppreference http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get and the new overloads return `const Type&&` from the `get<>()` functions.  Why would you want to return a `const Type&&` over just a regular `const Type&`?  You can't move from instances of either type..

For reference these are the function declarations I am referring to

```
template< class T, class... Types >
constexpr const T&& get(const tuple<Types...>&& t);
```

and

```
template< std::size_t I, class... Types >
constexpr std::tuple_element_t<I, tuple<Types...> >const&&
get( const tuple<Types...>&& t );
```

Comment: This way you can perfectly forward literals throw the whole call `double d = std::get<double>(std::make_tuple(1, "Foo", 3.14));`

Comment: @HenriMenke I think they're asking about returning, not forwarding.

Answer (score 4):

A google search turned up [Issue 2485](https://wg21.cmeerw.net/lwg/issue2485), which pointed to a flaw like this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std; 

string str1() { return "one"; }
const string str2() { return "two"; }
tuple<string> tup3() { return make_tuple("three"); }
const tuple<string> tup4() { return make_tuple("four"); }

int main() {
  // cref(str1()); // BAD, properly rejected
  // cref(str2()); // BAD, properly rejected
  // cref(get<0>(tup3())); // BAD, properly rejected
  cref(get<0>(tup4())); // BAD, but improperly accepted!
}
```

In this particular case, `cref` has a deleted overload for `const T&&`, but passing it through `get` is obscuring that the tuple, and its member, is a temporary.

Comment: I wonder why that overload is deleted from `std::cref`..  Rvalues would bind to the `const&` version anyway.  So what does safety does the deleted function provide?

Comment: Because if the argument passed to `std::cref` is a temporary, the pointer that it stores internally will no longer be valid as soon as the expression ends.  A major use case for `std::ref` and `std::cref` is to pass something by reference to a template function which would ordinarily make a copy, e.g. `std::bind` or `std::thread`

Comment: But wont the temporary bind to the `const&` version anyway?

Comment: Oh, I understand.  Binding to the `const&` is not allowed since the `const&&` version is deleted.  Just like move and copy constructors..  Am I right?

Comment: Correct.  Because the `const T&&` overload exists, it is selected as a better match over the `const T&` overload.  Since it is also deleted, it results in a compilation failure.

Answer (score 2):

You can move from mutable data from a `const&&`.  It is relatively obscure.

Comment: Oh! Didn't think about that.  But couldn't you do that for a regular `const&` anyway?

Comment: @curious you wouldn't know if you should.

Comment: @curious there is nothing you can do to `x&&` you cannot do to `x&` regardless of if there is a `const` or not.  An rvalue reference just says "you have permission to treat this as a temporary, and possibly steam state from it".  With `const&` you should not steal mutable state vs `const&&` you should.  How you should consume rvalue references is different than how you should consume lvalue references.